Output collections -> Elements estimated added/size estimation dataflow gcp don't shown
I'm using the JDK 17 and Apache Beam 2.50 and on the gcp dataflow graph and on the read from Avro/write to BigQuery I get the
READ RAW+ MESSAGES FROM AVRO file/Read.out0
Elements added : 332
Estimated size: 27.37 MB
After the upgrade the beam to the 2.54/2.55.1 I don't get any estimations but the files are fine read/write.
READ RAW+ MESSAGES FROM AVRO file/Read/ParDo(BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapper)/ParMultiDo(BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapper).out0
Elements added: –
Estimated size: –
The code is the same on my side but don't know where exactly to look.
I hope to get the same things on the dataflow job graph to be sure if something fail, or don't work properly, to have a clue.
